# I had hot glue holding something up on my wall as I had seen that it wouldn’t take off paint

Tags: drywall, paint, hanging

I went to remove the object to clean it and it peeled off part of my paint
I have white dry wall showing now and I don’t know how to cover it or put the item back up because it is quite heavy and will fall of with tape or the clay like wall stick stuff and it has no holes in it.

So how should hang up the item or fix the paint.

I need help quick I have a party tomorrow at my home and I can’t have this there as it is in the main party of my house.

Comment: Whatever led you to think that glue wouldn't peel paint?

Comment: As for how to hang the item - without knowing what the item is, how would you suggest we guess at proper methods of hanging?

Comment: Why not just put it back up with hot glue again? The paint is already peeled, you're not going to hurt it any more.

Comment: As for quick fixes - there isn't a good "quick" fix for the damaged wall.  Proper repair will take a few days, with spackle, sanding, and priming and painting.

Comment: Or put something lighter (such as a photo) on the wall to mask the damage until you have time to fix it properly.  If you do decide to hang the heavy object again, consider using something that embeds in the wall, such as a picture hook, nail, etc.  They hold a lot more weight than tape or poster putty, and the hole they leave behind is very easy to fill in.

Comment: the title of your post makes absolutely no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3M Command Strips. Make sure to leave the tabs accessible so that when it comes time to remove them, you can pull the tabs.

Comment: I like the command hooks but for a heavy load I prefer E-Z ancor they come in metal dicast or plasic. They are very simple to install with a drill or driver and they are easily removed with a screwdriver leaving a small hole I don't even look for a stud, if they stop because of a stud I put a screw in, running them flush. There rating depends on the size but they start at 50lbs and go up to 250. I use WAS-070 available at most home improvement stores for approx 30 cents ea.